# NavBar links not updating on redirect

Tags: angularjs

I am having a navigation bar directive which should produce the links depending on route (different for admin panel for example).

It all works fine when I am writing the address manually, but when I use:

```
<a href="admin">Link</a></footer>
```

link it redirects to the page, not loading the new links in nav bar (they stay the same as on the old page).

```
  directive('navBar', [
    function() {
      return {
        controller: function($scope, pagesFactory, $location) {
          var path = $location.path().substr(0, 6);
          if ($location.path() == "/admin/login")
            return;
          else if (path == "/admin") {
            $scope.navLinks = [{
              title: 'Pages',
              url: 'admin/pages'
            }, {
              title: 'Site Settings',
              url: 'admin/site-settings'
            }, ];
          } else {
            pagesFactory.getPages().then(
              function(response) {
                $scope.navLinks = response.data;
              }, function() {

              });
            }
          },
          templateUrl: 'partials/directives/nav.html'

        };
    }
  ])
```

Is there any way to run the controller after the path changes?

EDIT@1:

The same happends when I am trying to use $location.path('/admin/pages'); even if I use the $scope.apply() also.

Basicaly it is not reloading the directive when the path change is not manual.

FIXED using:

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() ...
```

Comment: Have you tried `/admin` in href attribute?

Comment: Yea it doesn't change anything, as I said the page loads but the partial doesn't reload.